# Printer not printing because of wrong size paper

Tags: pdf, printing

Our company recently upgraded its "bizhub" Konica Minolta printer to the latest version and this printer has been one hassle after another. Today, I tried to print a normal document and the printer went into error and basically shut down until it was manually reset. It complained that the "paper size is incorrect" and it apparently thinks the document is A4 and it refuses to print apparently unless I load it with A4 paper which I don't have because our company is in the United States and does not buy paper from Europe.

Here is what the print screen looks like:

[image]

How can I get this document to print? I have tried changing it to "Fit" but it makes no difference. Same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go into your printer properties and set the paper size there.

Uncheck "Choose paper size by PDF size".

Answer (score 0):

4 likely causes/fixes there:

1- Paper tray guides aren't properly set, and are telling the printer the paper is A4 based on the size they're set to - snug them up to the paper.

2- Printer's paper tray settings are manually set and specifying that the tray has A4 in it - check the settings on the printer (this might be your IT department's or the vendor's responsibility).

3- Printer drivers in Windows are specifying A4 - check your printer's settings from the Start menu, not from within the document.

4- PDF document itself specifies A4 (note that this would only apply to the one document, others from other places would work fine) - have the person that created the document fix it.

1 and 3 are probably most likely, certainly easiest to fix.